# How to get conversions metrics from LinkedIn APIs

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get some fields (conversion, conversionRate, conversionCost, etc.) from LinkedIn but documentation is obsolete [conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/conversion-tracking#report-statistics), the new doc is not updated [Metrics Available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#metrics-available). I Really need any help here. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get conversions metrics from LinkedIn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66343651/how-to-get-conversions-metrics-from-linkedin-api)

Answer (score 1):

the field refering conversion is externalWebsiteConversions

Answer (score 0):

```
externalWebsiteConversions = conversion
externalWebsitePostClickConversions = Post_Click_Conversions
externalWebsitePostViewConversions = View_Through_Conversions
```

For the rates/costs, you will need to compute by yourself like below:

```
    (Conversions/Clicks) AS Conversion_Rate,
    (Total_Spent/Conversions) AS Cost_per_Conversion,
```